# Unity3D Issue in Using Database in Windows Phone 8 (WP8) Build

Tags: database, sqlite, dll, windows-phone-8, unity-game-engine

I am facing some issue in using Sqlite Database in Windows Phone 8 in Unity3d.UNITY does not allow to build project in Windows Phone 8 if we use sqlite Database.Cause of problem  is use of System.Data.dll in Windows Phone 8 build.This dll runs perfect in other builds (Android , IOS ). I also tried different dlls like Microsoft's System.Data.dll, .Net 3.5 & 4.0 Framework System.Data.dll, Mono's System.Data.dll but none of this worked.

Have anyone used sqlite database in WP8 build in Unity3d ? if No, then how we can use Database in WP8 in Unity3d ?

Answer (score -1):

Try using the following SQLite library, it is very easy and tested on iOS, Android, and WP8:

[SQLiteUnityKit (Github)](https://github.com/Busta117/SQLiteUnityKit)